# jQuery deferred AJAX & 500 server errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, asmx

Trying to figure out how to debug generic 500 errors from my .ASMX

JS:

```
function TestError() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Order.asmx/TestError',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    });
}

$.when(TestError()).then(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object TestError()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Testing error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

It's not even logging the `err` argument.  Any ideas?

**Edit**

adding the error to the original Ajax call is getting me logging info, but still generic & useless.

http://i42.tinypic.com/2v27fgo.jpg

[image]

**Edit 2**

Answered my own question and have asked a follow-up:

[Removing properties of an inherited object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609805/removing-properties-of-an-inherited-object-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a kick in the right direction and further digging I actually found this problem was twofold.

First, [Dave Ward](http://encosia.com/) actually [pointed me in the right direction](https://twitter.com/#!/rerrify/status/149920402179756033) in suggesting I turn off `customErrors` in the web.config.  It was actually not that, but very close.

The actual culprit is the [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) error handling module.  After disabling it I was able to relay custom errors regardless of whether `customErrors` was `on` or `off`.

The second issue was that although I could now handle the errors, I still couldn't pass `System.Exception` objects.  I discovered this is because the `Exception.TargetSite` property is **not serializable**.

I got around the problem by creating my own `JsonException` class and only including the serializable properties of the `System.Exception` class (abbreviated here for simplicity).

```
public class JsonException
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }

    public JsonException(Exception ex)
    {
        this.Source = ex.Source;
        this.Message = ex.Message;
        this.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
    }
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public object TestError()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception("Testing error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonException(ex);
    }
}
```

And now I finally get the data I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would change to this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Order.asmx/TestError',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){ console.log(errorThrown); }
    });
```

Comment: That got the object logging to the console, still a generic "Internal Server Error", any idea how to get my custom message in there?

Comment: Try logging the other arguments - textStatus and XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: I did, doesn't help.  From jQuery.com docs - *When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."*

Comment: Are you sure your custom message is ever even being returned to the browser?  Can you see the full response (in, for example, the Network tab in Chrome developer tools, or Firebug)

Comment: No it is definitely not - I'm using Chrome dev tools. See edit w/ screenshot.

Comment: Oh and in case you were going to ask, if I stop throwing the exception and just return something successfully it **does** work.

Comment: Well, in that case it sounds like you need to change your .net code to  ensure your message does get sent back to the browser.  I can't help with that part, though - I'm no .Net developer.