# Removing properties of an inherited object in C#

Tags: c#, oop, serialization

**If I have a complex object, can I inherit from it and *remove* or *ignore* certain properties?**

If you don't care **why** I want to do this, feel free to just submit an answer.

If you do care, you can read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607862/jquery-deferred-ajax-500-server-errors).  To summarize it, I have an object that has a single property that is *not* serializable, and I want to serialize the entire object. The object in question is `System.Exception`

To get around the problem I wanted to simply create my own `JsonException` object, inherit all the lovely properties of the base (`System.Exception`) except remove (or empty) the ugly duckling (`Exception.TargetSite`).

Something like:

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    // Note this is not actually possible
    //      just demonstrating what I thought to do in theory
    public override System.Reflection.MethodBase TargetSite
    {
        get
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public MyException(string message)
        : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Also please keep in mind I am stuck with .NET 2.0 and really don't want to use custom serializers (like [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)) if I don't have to.

Comment: An exception *is* serializable... at least with binary serialization. Which kind of serialization are you using?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly but might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/390051/in-c-how-can-i-serialize-system-exception-net-cf-2-0

Comment: @ThomasLevesque The kind that gets called when I decorate a `WebMethod` with `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]` which I believe is [JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.serialize(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it without overriding the TargetSite property? I was able to do it (but not in 2.0, so I'm not sure if it will work for you like this

```
public class MyException : Exception
{
    public new System.Reflection.MethodBase TargetSite
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public MyException() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: So simple.  I'm overriding when all I had to do was hide it.  Thank you.

Comment: @jlafay as I have noted in an [edit request](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/165377), you _should use the `new` keyword_ in order to mark TargetSite as _hiding `Exception.TargetSite`_ - failure to do so generates a compiler warning.

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx) in the "Defining Exception classes" paragraph to see how to create a custom serializable exception.

Relevant part from the article:

```
[Serializable()]
public class InvalidDepartmentException : System.Exception
{
    public InvalidDepartmentException() : base() { }
    public InvalidDepartmentException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public InvalidDepartmentException(string message, System.Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }

    // A constructor is needed for serialization when an
    // exception propagates from a remoting server to the client. 
    protected InvalidDepartmentException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
        System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context) { }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer but jlafay's was actually an extremely simple workaround I am comfortable using and more directly answers my (somewhat generic) question.  Thank you! +1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [`IgnoreDataMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx) or the [`NonSerializedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)?

```
[IgnoreDataMember]
// or
[NonSerialized]
public override System.Reflection.MethodBase TargetSite
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The property is not overridable, abstract or virtual, so I can't decorate it unfortunately.